# Allow only letters, numbers, umlauts,+, -, and " in String

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a way to allow only letters `a-z, A-Z` Numbers, `+` , `-` and `"` in a string.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: look at the related column on the right- many answers, common question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$foo = preg_match('~[^A-Za-z0-9\+\-"]~', $string);
if($foo) echo "OH NO YOU HAVE A BAD CHARACTER";
```

Alternatively

```
$string = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9\+\-"]~', '', $string);
```

Comment: I would've gone with: `if($foo) echo "OH NO YOUR GOOGLE DOESN'T WORK";
`

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = preg_match('^[a-zA-Z0-9\+\*\"]', $string);
```